# while running meteor app i got this error message

Tags: meteor

```
iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/john/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/home/john/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "install" "connect@2.9.0"
npm ERR! cwd /home/john/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da/.npm/package-new-iwgw8d
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/john/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da/.npm/package-new-iwgw8d/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/john/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/home/john/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "install" "connect@2.9.0"
npm ERR! cwd /home/john/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da/.npm/package-new-19br3u6
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/john/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da/.npm/package-new-19br3u6/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors prevented startup:                  

While Building package `iron-router`:
error: couldn't install npm package

While Building package `iron-router`:
error: couldn't install npm package

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Try adding npm and then run meteor as administrator.

Comment: Your User has no access to /home/john/.npm/connect/2.9.0/package/package.json
Try: sudo chown -R john ~/.npm

Answer (score 0):

If you run your initial command with **user permissions** (which is not clear from your answer - please print the command next time), then it needs to be able to access (read, write, execute) other directories with the same permissions.

You can change ownership with:

```
chown -R $USER <directory>
```

where in your case `<directory>` is `/home/john` and `-R` is for recursive, so it will change all subdirectories too, which is exactly what  you want.

[See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787215/1614973).