# Npm start issues in AngularJS phonecat application

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I downloaded AngularJS phonecat application,and installed bower,http-server,karma,protractor globally. But when I move to directory with code and try 'npm start' ,it runs 'npm install' and shows the following error:

> > angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /Users/twer/angular-phonecat
> >
> > > npm install
>
> npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/bower-d21e2b2886728075.lock' npm WARN locking
>   at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/bower-d21e2b2886728075.lock failed { [Error:
>   EACCES, open '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/bower-d21e2b2886728075.lock']
>   npm WARN locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm
>   WARN locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/bower-d21e2b2886728075.lock' } npm ERR!
>   Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm
>   ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower, which hasn't been
>   locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/http-server-0dbc63e1ce281434.lock' npm WARN
>   locking     at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/http-server-0dbc63e1ce281434.lock failed {
>   [Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/http-server-0dbc63e1ce281434.lock'] npm WARN
>   locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm WARN
>   locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/http-server-0dbc63e1ce281434.lock' } npm ERR!
>   Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm
>   ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server, which hasn't
>   been locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/shelljs-e4f96e79494ea210.lock' npm WARN
>   locking     at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/shelljs-e4f96e79494ea210.lock failed { [Error:
>   EACCES, open '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/shelljs-e4f96e79494ea210.lock']
>   npm WARN locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm
>   WARN locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/shelljs-e4f96e79494ea210.lock' } npm ERR!
>   Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm
>   ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/shelljs, which hasn't been
>   locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-e8390a258c010e78.lock' npm WARN locking
>   at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-e8390a258c010e78.lock failed { [Error:
>   EACCES, open '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-e8390a258c010e78.lock']
>   npm WARN locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm
>   WARN locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-e8390a258c010e78.lock' } npm ERR!
>   Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm
>   ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma, which hasn't been
>   locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/protractor-a03b9e77140a9911.lock' npm WARN
>   locking     at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/protractor-a03b9e77140a9911.lock failed {
>   [Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/protractor-a03b9e77140a9911.lock'] npm WARN
>   locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm WARN
>   locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/protractor-a03b9e77140a9911.lock' } npm ERR!
>   Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" npm
>   ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor, which hasn't
>   been locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-chrome-launcher-4c47483197e76b06.lock'
>   npm WARN locking     at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-chrome-launcher-4c47483197e76b06.lock
>   failed { [Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-chrome-launcher-4c47483197e76b06.lock']
>   npm WARN locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm
>   WARN locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-chrome-launcher-4c47483197e76b06.lock'
>   } npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
>   "install" npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher, which
>   hasn't been locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-jasmine-435fcdaa8b86b427.lock' npm WARN
>   locking     at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-jasmine-435fcdaa8b86b427.lock failed {
>   [Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-jasmine-435fcdaa8b86b427.lock'] npm
>   WARN locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm WARN
>   locking   path:
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/karma-jasmine-435fcdaa8b86b427.lock' } npm
>   ERR! Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma-jasmine, which hasn't
>   been locked npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/tmp-44bc7858c2a6d09a.lock' npm WARN locking
>   at Error (native) npm WARN locking 
>   /Users/twer/.npm/_locks/tmp-44bc7858c2a6d09a.lock failed { [Error:
>   EACCES, open '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/tmp-44bc7858c2a6d09a.lock'] npm
>   WARN locking   errno: -13, npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES', npm WARN
>   locking   path: '/Users/twer/.npm/_locks/tmp-44bc7858c2a6d09a.lock' }
>   npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
>   "install" npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>
> npm ERR! Attempt to unlock
>   /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/node_modules/tmp, which hasn't been
>   locked
>
> npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
>   "start" npm ERR! node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4 npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script 'npm install'. npm ERR! This is
>   most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package, npm ERR! not
>   with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your
>   system: npm ERR!     npm install npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/twer/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you may have installed code using `sudo` before, creating root-owned files. Try this: `sudo chown -R $USER /Users/twer/.npm/`

Comment: I tried what you suggested and still had some problems. But when I try 'sudo npm start', it works .Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These errors mean that `npm` cannot access the directory `/Users/twer` and its subdirectories because of the wrong permissions.

You want to run `npm` with your own user permission, so set them with by changing the ownership with

```
chown -R $USER <directory>
```

or

```
chown -R `whoami` <directory>
```

-- both commands do the same, where `<directory>` is:

- your home directory (`/Users/twer`) for local installations;
- your machine directory for non-system packages, `/usr/local` or whatever top directory is `npm` trying to use, that you see in your error messages, you would likely need to prefix your command with `sudo` in that case.

The option `-R` here is for **recursive** as it sets correct ownership also to all subdirectories, which is exactly what you want.

You want to **avoid** running `npm` with `sudo` ever, as [recommended by the `npm` creator Isaac Schlueter](http://foohack.com/):

> **I strongly encourage you not to do package management with sudo!** Packages can run arbitrary scripts, which makes sudoing a package manager command as safe as a chainsaw haircut. Sure, it’s fast and definitely going to cut through any obstacles, but you might actually want that obstacle to stay there.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else - only the $HOME/_locks directory was owned by root on my Mac OS. Must have used sudo.. changed the ownership and viola!